# Request authorization failed when trying to access Graph.User[id].Authorization.PhoneMethods

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have SPA where users log in using adb2c.
SPA uses backend microservice.

We want to enable users to view/upadte their 2FA phone methods.

When I try to make a request like `GraphClient.Users[id].Authentication.PhoneMethods.GetAsync()` I get an error that authorization failed.

On the other hand, when I try to do request like `GraphClient.Me.Authentication.PhoneMethods.GetAsync()` (where I made an instance of a `graphClient` using `jwt` token user got when logging into SPA) then i get an error that jwt scopes are not right.

My understanding is that I need to use delegated permissions but I am not sure what does that involve? Is that something just to be turned on once or does each user have to give a consent that API can access their `PhoneMethods`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-phonemethods?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions-acting-on-other-users) and it seems that the endpoint is quite secure and requires `UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All` to read phone methods of other users.

To have only `UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All` permission is not enough. The authenticated user must have [Microsoft Entra Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/permissions-reference?toc=%2Fgraph%2Ftoc.json) either **Global Reader** or **Privileged Authentication Administrator**.

Comment: so, if I understand you correctly...are you saying that for application permission type, `UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All` is enough but for delegated permission type is not?

Comment: @dzg For services that use application permissions, UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All should be enough.

Comment: yes, that works now with respect to authorization but it doesn't return any result. Is it possible that this works only in `beta` and not in regular version?